# python syntax error w3af

Tags: python, syntax

I am getting a syntax error in a python file and I'm really new to python.

```
if o in ('-r', '--revision'):
            doupdate = True
            a = a.upper()
            if a in ('HEAD', 'PREV'):
                rev = 0 if (a == 'HEAD') else -1
            else:
                try:
                    rev = int(a)
                except ValueError:
                    om.out.error("Invalid value for revision number. Expected int.")
                    return -3

    # console
```

This is not all of the file.. The bad line is `rev = 0 if (a == 'HEAD') else -1`

Thanks

Comment: Please always post the traceback you get when asking about an exception you got. Your bad line seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old version of Python.

The if-expression was added in 2.5.

Your code compiles fine for me.